Why did I lose a point of rating in stalemate?
Recently played this game on chess.com and it ended up in a stalemate then also I lost one rating and the opponent gained one rating. How is this possible as I have more points in the end?

Edit: For clarity I was referring to the rating

Does this answer your question? How do you calculate elo?

The question isn't about stalemate at all; this is for questions about what stalemate is, or why a position is stalemate. You appear to understand perfectly well that the game was a draw; the question is about the consequence on rating of having a drawn game - and in this case it doesn't matter why the game is a draw.

Anyway, do have a look at that game review if you want to improve at chess, and also try to take a more organized approach to understanding the endgame. I assume you already know that you won't checkmate if you have only a knight, and I assume you have the goal of promoting one of those pawns so that you can get a better piece that you could use to checkmate the opponent. Therefore, your first priority should be to keep the opponent's king out of the way of your advancing pawns, by using your own king and checks from your knight to protect the squares in front of your pawns.

In a recent USCF game I played against a much stronger player, I lost but didn't change my rating at all, but my opponent gained a single point. Depending on how the formula goes the rating change isn't the same. Or it could just be a rounding error.

You probably lost rating. This is a number that represents how good the platform thinks you are at chess (higher = better). In general if you beat someone who's rated higher than you, you will gain rating points, and the higher-rated they were compared to you, the more you gain.
Since you were rated higher than your opponent, you were expected to win.* Since you didn't win, you lost rating points while opponent gained it. The material count in the end position doesn't matter.
*More accurately, since the change is small, you were expected to draw - but if one party won, you were considered more likely to win than your opponent.
